# cursor freezes or dissapears

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I have a Toshiba satellite c850 running windows 8.1 where the cursor freezes or disappears at random times. Sometimes the `F5` key works, other times I have to push the power button, but when neither works I have to go for a full restart, but may have the same problem 5 mins later. I have tried searching for updates for drivers, and scanned the computer with spy bot and bit defender. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, one of the function keys on the laptop has a *'switch the mouse pointer on or off'* feature.  This is something I have never seen before, despite having used laptops since they were practically first available.

On your particular laptop (Toshiba Satellite C850) the F5 key does this.  It has a picture which is hardly identifiable as a mouse with a line through it.
Press this (or press FN+F5 depending on you configuration), and hey presto... the cursor returns.

Comment: sometimes the f5 key works but more often It does not. Tried with and without the FN key but on no difference. Some evenings might have to reboot 2 or 3 times

Comment: Hmmmm. . . Does it disappear at specific times. For example - when you are typing?